# Method to parse multiple .html files and remove part of html code

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing, debian-stretch

what is the proper way to parse multiple .html files within directory, search and remove part of html code in these files?
For example, I need to remove a html code from all files:

```
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Book Search</h2>
        <div id="search">
            <form action="http://www.biology35.com/search.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="searchfor" class="txtField" />
                <input type="image" src="new/images/btn-go.png" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
                <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I use Geany 1.29 file editor on Debian. Regex is probably not suitable for this. Some shell script or python?

Comment: Just copy the HTML literally and escape any chars which have special meaning in regex. Here is a start: `<div class=\"box\">\s*<h2>Book Search<\/h2>\s*<div id=\"search\">\s*` https://regex101.com/r/BuPSZr/1/

Comment: Did you have a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/)?

Comment: @sophros I've installed this library, BeautifulSoup 4, for Python 2.x. looked at some examples in documentation, but as I've never used it before, it requires a lot of learning for first-time users, still can't figure out how to apply it to my task.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: it works and is helpful for me as regex example, but I have 8 code segments in each of multiple html documents that I need to edit. Not sure how this can be done for multiple documents at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htql, for example:

```
html = """
something before
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Book Search</h2>
        <div id="search">
            <form action="http://www.biology35.com/search.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="searchfor" class="txtField" />
                <input type="image" src="new/images/btn-go.png" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
                <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

html after
"""

import htql
x=htql.query(html, "<div norecur (class='box') > &delete ")[0][0]
```

You get:

```
>>> x
'\nsomething before\n    \n\nhtml after\n'
```